# install custom kernel and rootfs on board SMDKV210

Tags: linux, boot, kernel, embedded

I need help to install custom uboot + kernel + rootfs on a device with board SMDKV210 (device is panel INEWTEK)

So the fact is that worked on a device (inewtek) with board SMDKV210 (call it old board so OB).
I was given a list of commands (uboot) and files (uboot + kernel + rootfs) to install our custom linux os and application on this board via serial port.
This worked perfectly.

But inewtek decided to update their product so now they sell us a new panel with board SMDKV210 (call it new board so NB).

My job is to install our custom linux os and application on this board.

Of course I am new to embedded environment so I am a bit lost.

Inewtek gave me original files  (uboot + kernel + rootfs) for the new board, and I have of course our custom files.

For now I am only able to install our custom kernel on this NB, but I cannot install the custom rootfs (do we say ramdisk ?).

So bellow I give you :
Procedure and commands we used to install custom os on the OB.
Procedure and commands to install original os on NB
Procedure and commands I tried to install custom kernel and rootfs on NB
The boot trace to show the error I'm stuck at.

I think I made an error on memory addresses but I can't see the issue cause the display stop after "starting kernel...".
I read it could be because my kernel sends messages on an other output.

So please help me on this, our (very little) company can't sell product anymore.

### Commands to install  custom os on old board

```
setenv serverip 192.168.0.5 //tftp server ip
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.20 // panel ip
tftp 20008000 u-boot.bin // get the custom uboot
nand erase 0 40000
nand write 20008000 0 40000
tftp 20008000 PROD-zImageMTD3 // get the custom kernel
nand erase 40000 3C0000
nand write 20008000 40000 3C0000
tftp 20008000 PROD-zImageMTD2 // get a custom temporary ramdisk we will boot on, then we could copy rootfs to mtdblock3
bootm 20008000  
cd /tmp
mkdir mnt
tftp -g -r PROD-RFS-2015-06-10.tar 192.168.0.5 // get custom rootfs
flash_eraseall -j /dev/mtd3
mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock3 mnt
ls mnt // should be empty
tar -xf PROD-RFS-2015-06-10.tar -C mnt // install custom rootfs
ls mnt should see all the files and folder (etc, usr, dev, var, root ...)
umount mnt
reboot
```

### Commands to install original os on new board)

```
nand erase clean;nand scrub;setenv serverip 192.168.0.5;setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.20
setenv up_uboot tftp 24000000 S5PV210_2016/u-boot.bin\;nand erase 0 60000\;nand write 24000000 0 60000;run up_uboot
setenv up_kernel tftp 24000000 S5PV210_2016/zImage\;nand erase 00600000 00300000\;nand write 24000000 00600000 00300000
setenv up_ramdisk tftp 24000000 S5PV210_2016/linux-ramdisk.gz\;nand erase 00b00000 00a00000\;nand write 24000000 00b00000 00a00000
setenv bootargs console=ttySAC2,115200 init=/linuxrc ethaddr=$ethaddr slram=dmc1,0x40000000,+0x10000000
setenv bootcmd nand read 20008000 600000 300000\;nand read 21000000 b00000 a00000\;bootm 20008000 21000000
saveenv
run up_kernel;run up_ramdisk
(reboot manually)
```

### Commands to install custom os on new board (DO NOT WORK)

```
setenv serverip 192.168.0.5
setenv ipaddr 192.168.0.20
setenv up_kernel tftp 24000000 PROD-zImageMTD3\;nand erase 00600000 003C0000\;nand write 24000000 00600000 003C0000
setenv up_ramdisk tftp 24000000 PROD-zImageMTD2\;nand erase 00b00000 00a00000\;nand write 24000000 00b00000 00a00000
setenv bootargs root=/dev/mtdblock3 rootfstype=cramfs console=ttySAC1,115200 init=/linuxrc ethaddr=$ethaddr slram=dmc1,0x40000000,+0x10000000
setenv bootcmd nand read 20008000 600000 003C0000\;nand read 21000000 b00000 a00000\;bootm 20008000 21000000
saveenv
run up_kernel;run up_ramdisk
(reboot manually)
```

boot trace with error

```
NAND read: device 0 offset 0x600000, size : 0x3c0000
 3932160 bytes read: OK

NAND read: device 0 offset 0xb00000, size : 0xa00000
 10485760 bytes read: OK
Boot with zImage
The input address don't need a virtual-to-physical translation : 20008000
get_format
-------- 1 --------
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 21000000 ...
   Image Name:   ramdisk
   Created:      2015-06-23   1:58:07 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    8863276 Bytes =  8.5 MB
   Load Address: 20800000
   Entry Point:  20800000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Comment: Using the `nand scrub` command is unwise, as that changes "bad" blocks into "good".  You say that there are *"old"* and *"new"* boards, yet they have the same names, *"SMDKV210"*, and you're using the same kernel, PROD-zImageMTD3?  Have you verified that the length numbers are sufficient (i.e what are the length results of the tftp operations)?  Your *"Commands to install custom os on old board"* are not equivalent to *"Commands to install custom os on new board"* -- You're writing a zImage to the partition marked "rootfs"!!!  What happens when you use the old board commands on the new board?

Comment: Why are your image files misnamed?  `PROD-zImageMTD2` apparently has a U-Boot wrapper, so it is actually a uImage file.

Comment: oh sorry, the old board is not SMDKV210 but SMDKC100 .
yes I try to install custom kernel on the now board. is that a mistake ?
yes length seems to be ok
When I use all the old commands (and old files uboot, kernel and rootfs) on the new board, I get a NAND ERROR CHECKSUM + Uart negotiation Error at reboot.

Comment: I don't know why are image files misnamed